# What is the name of the RStudio package, containing `define_rng`

Tags: install.packages

I typed in some data into RStudio, which involved the `define_rng` package, and therefore needed it to be defined.
I was prompted to type in `library("define_rng")` but it said I needed the name of the package which contains it, so I can type in `library("package_name")`, where `package_name` is the name of the package containing `define_rng`. I was just wondering, does anybody here know, what the package is called, please?
Thank you very much in advance and kind regards,
Alec Brown

Comment: It's from `hesim`, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hesim/versions/0.5.3/topics/define_rng

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply -- thanks very much :)